# Unable to check valid date using SimpleParseDate.parse

Tags: java, simpledateformat

I am trying to check a date for validation. Below is my code. When I check for the date **12/12/2014XYZ**, SimpleDateFormat.parse does not throw exception. With other invalid dates like **13/13/2014** it is throwing exception.

```
public class DateCheck{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
        sdf.setLenient(false);
        try {
            sdf.parse("12/31/2014XYZ");
            System.out.println("Valid Date");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Invalid Date");

        }
    }
}
```

I googled a lot but could not find the proper solution.

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3025942/is-this-a-java-dateformat-bug

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `ParsePosition` as follows:

```
try {
    String input = "12/31/2014XYZ";

    ParsePosition pp = new ParsePosition(0);
    sdf.parse(input, pp);

    // Make sure the entire string was parsed
    if (pp.getIndex() != input.length())
        throw new Exception();

    System.out.println("Valid Date");
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Invalid Date");
}
```

Similar questions:

- [Why does DecimalFormat allow characters as suffix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4324997/why-does-decimalformat-allow-characters-as-suffix)
- [Is this a Java DateFormat bug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3025942/is-this-a-java-dateformat-bug)

Answer (score 0):

This is as described in the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#parse-java.lang.String-):

> Parses text from the beginning of the given string to produce a date. **The method may not use the entire text of the given string.**

So your observation is the behaviour that is expected and described.

Answer (score 0):

As you have told the date format "MM/dd/yyyy" so it will check only first four characters after "/"

if you write the date as "12/31/XYZ2014" it will throw an exception and invalid date will be printed.

Answer (score 0):

From Java [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#parse-java.lang.String-).

> Parses text from the beginning of the given string to produce a date.
>   The method may not use the entire text of the given string.

So it will take `12/31/2014` only from `12/31/2014XYZ` and take as valid format.

Eg:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
try {
    java.util.Date date=sdf.parse("12/31/2014AnyThing");
    System.out.println("Valid Date "+date);
   } catch (ParseException e) {
    System.out.println("Invalid Date");
   }
try {
    java.util.Date date=sdf.parse("AnyThing12/31/2014");
    System.out.println("Valid Date "+date);
   } catch (ParseException e) {
    System.out.println("Invalid Date");
  }
```

Out put:

```
  Valid Date Wed Dec 31 00:00:00 IST 2014
  Invalid Date
```

Same as here.

```
   SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
    try {
        java.util.Date date=sdf.parse("12/31/2014XYZ");
        System.out.println("Valid Date "+date);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        System.out.println("Invalid Date");

    }

    try {
        java.util.Date date=sdf.parse("XYZ12/31/2014");
        System.out.println("Valid Date "+date);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        System.out.println("Invalid Date");

    }
```

Out put:

```
   Valid Date Wed Dec 31 00:00:00 IST 2014
   Invalid Date
```

Edit:

@aioobe answer will provide the solution for not take this as valid date format.

Comment: But it doesn't work for the example provided by the OP: "12/31/2014XYZ"

Comment: "12/31/2014XYZ" does't look like a valid date to me.

Comment: @aioobe am I saying any different thing?

Comment: Yes: `Valid Date Wed Dec 31 00:00:00 IST 2014`

Comment: @aioobe that's why i am saying `12/31/2014XYZ` considered as valid one since post `XYZ` is ignore as it clearly said in http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#parse-java.lang.String-

Comment: @aioobe Now you tell me what is the meaning of this `But it doesn't work for the example provided by the OP: "12/31/2014XYZ"`

Comment: The OP clearly stated that he does *not* want "12/31/2014XYZ" to be considered a valid date. Your answer is basically "It *is* a valid date, see the docs".

Comment: @aioobe i said why it is happening.

Comment: ...which of course is of very limited help to the OP :-)

Comment: @aioobe seems to be you are master in this particular question since past. :)

Comment: @aioobe I keep this answer since I feel It should be. And updated my answer mentioning the solution is in your answer. and 1+